# Androidx java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and android.view.InflateException: at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androidx, google-play-console

After I migrate to Androidx library, I am getting this error in Google Play Dev Console.

**Crash Report from Google Play:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3322)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3418)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5481)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:231)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1829)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7422)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:551)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:380)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
  at x.y.z.LoginActivity.onCreate (LoginActivity.java:24)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6904)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3269)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:788)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:966)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:843)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:595)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:776)
```

**EDIT2:**

**layout/toolbar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**EDIT:**

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
package x.y.z;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import androidx.core.app.Fragment;
//import androidx.core.app.FragmentManager;
//import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import x.y.z.common.ActivityBase;

public class LoginActivity extends ActivityBase {

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    Fragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "currentFragment");

        } else {

            fragment = new LoginFragment();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "currentFragment", fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home: {

                finish();
                return true;
            }

            default: {

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_login.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="x.y.z.LoginActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:name="ru.ifsoft.network.LoginFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
//Imported libraries.    
public class MainActivity extends ActivityBase implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener, ImageChooseDialog.AlertPositiveListener, ProfileReportDialog.AlertPositiveListener, PopularSettingsDialog.AlertPositiveListener {

        Toolbar mToolbar;

        private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

        // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    LinearLayout mContainerAdmob;

    Fragment fragment;
    Boolean action = false;
    int page = 0;

    private Boolean restore = false;
    Boolean entered = false;

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            //Restore the fragment's instance
            fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "currentFragment");

            restore = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("restore");
            mTitle = savedInstanceState.getString("mTitle");

        } else {

            fragment = new StreamFragment();

            restore = false;
            mTitle = getString(R.string.app_name);
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
        }

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        mContainerAdmob = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_admob);



        mContainerAdmob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.bringToFront();

        if (!restore) {

            // Show default section "Stream"

            displayView(1);
        }


    }


    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean("restore", true);
        outState.putString("mTitle", getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString());
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "currentFragment", fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ACTION_LOGIN && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            String pageId = data.getStringExtra("pageId");

            switch (pageId) {

                case "favorites": {

                    displayView(5);

                    break;
                }

                case "notifications": {

                    displayView(6);

                    break;
                }

                case "profile": {

                    displayView(7);

                    break;
                }


                case "settings": {


                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    break;
                }

                default: {

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChangePopularCategory(int position) {

        PopularFragment p = (PopularFragment) fragment;
        p.onChangeCategory(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageFromGallery() {

        ProfileFragment p = (ProfileFragment) fragment;
        p.imageFromGallery();
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageFromCamera() {

        ProfileFragment p = (ProfileFragment) fragment;
        p.imageFromCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProfileReport(int position) {

        ProfileFragment p = (ProfileFragment) fragment;
        p.onProfileReport(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {

        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {

        action = false;

        switch (position) {

            case 0: {

                break;
            }

            case 1: {

                page = 1;

                fragment = new StreamFragment();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.page_1);

                action = true;

                break;
            }

            case 2: {

                page = 2;

                fragment = new CategoriesFragment();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.page_2);

                action = true;

                break;
            }


            case 3: {

                page = 3;

                fragment = new SearchFragment();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

                action = true;

                break;
            }

            case 4: {

                page = 4;

                fragment = new PopularFragment();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.page_4);

                action = true;

                break;
            }

            case 5: {

                if (App.getInstance().getId() != 0){

                    page = 5;

                    fragment = new FavoritesFragment();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.page_5);

                    action = true;

                } else {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("pageId", "favorites");
                    startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_LOGIN);
                }

                break;
            }


            case 6: {

                if (App.getInstance().getId() != 0){

                    page = 6;

                    fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.page_6);

                    action = true;

                } else {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("pageId", "notifications");
                    startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_LOGIN);
                }

                break;
            }


            case 7: {

                if (App.getInstance().getId() != 0){

                    page = 7;

                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.page_7);

                    action = true;

                } else {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("pageId", "profile");
                    startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_LOGIN);
                }

                break;
            }
            case 8: {
                //Log.d("case8","case8");

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "x.y.z");
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
                // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
                goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                try {
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "x.y.z")));
                }
                break;
            }

            case 9: {

                //Log.d("case8","son");

                if (App.getInstance().getId() != 0) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                } else {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("pageId", "settings");
                    startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_LOGIN);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        if (action) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_body, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home: {

                return true;
            }

            default: {

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {

            drawerFragment.closeDrawer();

        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {

        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    public void hideAds() {

        if (App.getInstance().getAdmob() == ADMOB_DISABLED) {

            mContainerAdmob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

In my Lg G2 4.4.2 and Nexus Emulators(8.0 - 9.0), there was a no problem.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/container_admob"
            android:visibility="gone">


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="x.y.z.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Finally, how can I solve the problem? What is(or may be) the main reason?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: i think the issue is in LoginActivity

Comment: @SalmanAziz Hmm, Let me edit the code.

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: What is an exception message? Which class it can't find?

Comment: show us your include toolbar. as it says ```android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:966)```
I think the problem is in your `@layout/toolbar`

Comment: @GV_FiQst You are wonderful!! Answer the question please! I will add reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `@layout/toolbar` as it says `android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:966)` in your stacktrace. Try to check if your toolbar view is correct.

Comment: The problem was in land/tooldbar.xml. That's why no problem in my LG G2 and emulator. Then, you saved my time! Thanks again